# How could the whole series of graphics be saved?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, export

I would like to save a series of graphics of a function as pictures. But the problem is that I can't manipulate the name of the graphs, because of that only the last graphics in the series is saved.

How could the whole series of graphics be saved?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

gr[B_, i_] := B*2*i^2

For[i = 1, i < 5, i++,
 GE[i_] := Table[{B, gr[B, i]}, {B, 0, 9, 1}];
 Export["C:/.../graphic.pdf", 
  ListPlot[Table[{GE[i][[l, 1]], GE[i][[l, 2]]}, {l, 1, 10}], 
   PlotRange -> All]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Use `StringJoin` (`<>`) and `ToString` to give each plot a separate filename based on `i`

```
Export["C:/.../graph"<>ToString[i]<>".pdf",...]
```

Edit: building off Nasser's answer, it probably is just easier to put everything on one plot:

```
GE[i_] := Table[{B, gr[B, i]}, {B, 0, 9}];
p= ListPlot[ Table[GE[i], {i, 5}], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
Export["filepath/figName.pdf",p]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would not do things like this, but this makes your code at least work. More functional style can be done on this. ps. also avoid `For`. I assume you want all plots in one pdf file.

```
GE=First@Last@Reap@Do[
   Sow[Table[{B,gr[B,i]},{B,0,9,1}]]
   ,
   {i,1,4}
];
p=Table[Table[{GE[[i,l,1]],GE[[i,l,2]]},{l,1,10}],{i,1,4}]
Export["p.pdf",ListPlot[ p]]
```

[image]